# Processing ZIP entries without central control file

Tags: c#, zip

My company used to use a product called DynaZip which is no longer supported and the company is defunct. Through trial and error I have found out that most likely the data stored in our databases is in ZIP terms, a single ZipEntry, as its header signature is 50 4B 01 02, instead of the expected 50 4B 03 04. Is there any way I can use any other available libraries, commercial or open source, to continue to compress and decompress our single entry "files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the answer of this question solves your problem:

**[Is there a way to decompress a DynaZip Max file with another library? F.E. DotNetZip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671968/is-there-a-way-to-decompress-a-dynazip-max-file-with-another-library-f-e-dotne)**

Comment: You are Freaking Awesome! And so is user2671330!